# 'impersonate as' or 'impersonate' someone?

Tags: word-usage, phrasal-verbs

Is the following use of **impersonate** correct?

> In reality, the ring contained pig blood, which Evans, **impersonating as** the injured McLeery, would splatter on his head and escape from the prison.

I encountered this usage in a reference textbook for school.

This is the first instance I saw 'as' following 'impersonate', and I want to know how it makes sense, if it does.

I consulted several online dictionaries and found following such usages:

'References in classical literature' in [The Free Dictionary](https://www.thefreedictionary.com/impersonating)

> ISLAMABAD -- The Secretariat Police have arrested two members of a gang who have been looting gullible people by **impersonating as** officials of sensitive institutions of the country.

And

> KARACHI -- Sindh Rangers have apprehended three fake polling staffers including one **impersonating as** Presiding Officer at a polling station established in a private school near Nishtar Park, off Soldier Bazar.

Also, [Wordweb](https://wordweb.info/free/) has [this](https://www.dropbox.com/s/mb3zthdbqgvwrpo/Wordweb%20Impersonate.png?dl=0) example

> She **impersonated as** the Czar's daughter

Comment: The natural structure would be impersonate. However, using along with as also makes perfect sense and is grammatical as well. You will find some examples of the latter form in formal writing of more recent origin.

Comment: Seems like ***impersonating as*** is used when actually trying to take the place of someone.  Just *impersonating* can be done for comedic effect on a variety show, for example, when there is no intention to disguise.